# Pure CSS solution for overflow:auto and max-height setting on window size changes

Tags: css

Assume two divs. A is static but B adapts its height on window change. In general that is easy to achieve but I need vertical scrollbars if the content does not fit into B and so I currently change the max-height option via Javascript if the window size changes and use `overflow:auto` for the css of B.

```
-----
| A |
-----
| B |
-----
```

Is this possible without JavaScript?

As calculating the height gets complicated if the you have sub-sub-sub... components of B. And e.g. using `position:fixed` does not trigger the scrollbars.

Comment: There are currently two close votes; one saying they don't know what you're asking and one saying they need to see teh codez.

Comment: Seems like a clear enough question to me. And constrained enough that code isn't immediately necessary, while an answer might be useful in the future.

Answer (score 3):

not sure if this is what you mean, but you could use this approach.
You need a wrapper around this two divs and than add the following CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  heigth: 100vh       /* means use full window height */;
}
.static {
  height: 300px       /* what ever your height is */;
}
.flexible {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

See fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3np6dq1k/). But be aware of browser-support for [flex-property](http://caniuse.com/#search=display%3A%20flex) and [vh-units](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh), because these are not supported in older browsers.

Comment: Never heard about the flex property - thanks! This seems to be what I meant - I'll play with it!